# utf8 and unicode getting warning messages in mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a mysql table.  When I try to insert, I get this:

Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xAE</...' for column 'value' at row 1

```
mysql> show create table Configurations;
| Configurations | CREATE TABLE `Configurations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ckey` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ckey` (`ckey`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I googled the hell out of the error, and it all seemed to boil down to utf8 being set as my default character set.  I've been like that for a while.  I'm not sure what else to do.  Help?

Comment: Can you give an example of an insert statement causing the warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You could try these-

1. Check what the encoding of the string is before you enter them into your DB, which probably expects it in `utf8`.
2. **[This guy suggests](http://yoonkit.blogspot.com/2006/03/mysql-charset-from-latin1-to-utf8.html)** you update each of your table columns to take in `utf8`.